# Google Maps API v2 без Play Services

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Решил использовать Google maps api v2!
Но сразу проблема:(

1) для работы с картами, у пользователя обязательно должно быть установлено приложение «Карты» от самого Google.

2) ебз приложения “Сервисы Google Play”  так-же не работает (если даже версия устарела)

- Можно вообще решить эту проблему? т.е. как-то обойти? Вроде как в сети пишут что в 1ой версии такого не было..
- Есть ли возможность при использовании OSMDroid карты наложить на него титлы google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Github есть репозиторий [airbnb/AirMapView](https://github.com/airbnb/AirMapView), созданный для решения именно этой проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое! Сейчас попробую)

Comment: Вы не использовали данную либу? если можно, есть вопрос: Можно ли его использовать во фрагменте? Как? В примере, использование в Activity.. Беглый поиск результатов не дал(

Comment: Не использовал. Нашел в гугле с первой попытки. `Google Maps without Play Services`. По второму вопросу тоже всё просто. Оказалось, что это стандартная возможность библиотеки. Находится по запросу `AirMapView fragment`

Comment: я пробую так: 


View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fast_order, null);
AirMapView mapView = (AirMapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
mapView.initialize(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

Но у меня ошибка java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions . Для добавления фрагментов использую FragmentTransaction..

Comment: Сами не пробовали поискать? Если не нашли, задавайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: Пробовал и все еще ищу..(возможно ключевые слова не так подбираю) Не хотел плодить много тем..

Comment: Stackoverflow это Q&A. Плодить темы приветствуется, обсуждение в комментариях - нет